# Gradle sync failur when creating new kotlin project: (ModuleVersionResolveException)

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I received the following error when I wanted to create a new kotlin project in IntelliJ IDE. What shall I do?

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve gradle:gradle:7.4.2.

Comment: It might be network issues

Comment: If you're behind a corporate proxy make sure it is properly configured in the IDE https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-http-proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

With Thanks for comments, I realized that I was suffering an inappropriate proxy setting.So after geting rid of the proxy, the problem solved.